# Rabl: Multiple nodes with the same name

Tags: ruby, xml, rabl

I have the following code for generating a xml from a rabl template:

```
obj = OpenStruct.new
obj.categories = [{node: ["Foo","Bar"]},{node: ["Test1","Test2"]}]
Rabl::Renderer.xml(obj, 'adapter_xml')
```

and this is the rabl template `adapter_xml.rabl`

```
object @obj => :root
attributes :categories
```

which generates this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <categories>
    <category>
      <node>
        <node>Foo</node>
        <node>Bar</node>
      </node>
    </category>
    <category>
      <node>
        <node>Test1</node>
        <node>Test2</node>
      </node>
    </category>
  </categories>
</root>
```

But what I want to achieve is the following format, without the extra `<node>` tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <categories>
    <category>
      <node>Foo</node>
      <node>Bar</node>
    </category>
    <category>
      <node>Test1</node>
      <node>Test2</node>
    </category>
  </categories>
</root>
```

Is there any way to do this with rabl? Or do I have to modify the ruby code mentioned first?

Comment: Give us the full code you are using.

Comment: ups, sorry. I forgot the rabl template. The question is updated